# Why does `history -s` wipe my command history?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, ssh, history

I am working on a project where the STG and LIVE environments have multiple instances, including a central 'gfs' server where you can do database admin

You access all of the instances via a 'bastion' server, but ssh-ing twice, almost always to 'gfs' gets irritating so I added some shortcut to the bash profile so that I can just write `!!` when I get on to the bastion server to get to gfs

I added this line to my users' `.bashrc` on the bastion server:

`history -s 'gcloud compute ssh [some-instance]  --internal-ip --ssh-flag="-o ServerAliveInterval=30"'`

But after that when I log in all previous history is always deleted except for that command added.
When I run `history -s [command]` in an interactive shell it doesn't have the same behaviour.

Does anyone have an idea as to what might be the problem?

In case it is relevant, problem occurs on Red Hat Enterprise v7.9

Comment: Just in case anyone is trying to solve the same problem with ssh-ing through a bastion server, please do not attempt the same as I was, ssh proxy commands are a much better solution, basic concept here: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-ssh-proxycommand-passing-through-one-host-gateway-server/
Using your google cloud IPs (bastion and app/caching/DB servers etc.) plus a bastion 'jumpserver' you should be able to configure ssh such that you can simply write `ssh [hostname]` and have the proxy command handled automatically. IMO it is 100% worth the setup

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to find any documentation on how and when *exactly* Bash loads the history file ("When the shell starts up, the history is initialized…" does not really say when). Nevertheless my tests in Bash 5.1.16 indicate that:

1. the history file is automatically loaded *after* sourcing `.bashrc`,
2. but only if the history in the current shell is still empty at this point.

IMO it's not a bad design. These are my observations:

- (1) allows you to easily customize the history in `.bashrc`, e.g. you can set `HISTFILE` to a non-default value and it will just work. If the default history file was loaded before you are able to set `HISTFILE`, a mechanism or a manual solution to discard the just-loaded history and to load the right file would be needed; this would be less elegant.
- (2) allows you to build history "by hand" using commands in `.bashrc` (possibly conditionally), without worrying that eventually something else will be appended in a way you cannot easily control.

Your `history -s …` suppressed (1) because of (2).

The solution is quite simple: in `.bashrc` put `history -r` (i.e. load the history file) before `history -s …`.

```bash
history -r
history -s 'gcloud compute ssh [some-instance]  --internal-ip --ssh-flag="-o ServerAliveInterval=30"'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am not sure if I will have time to set this up again as I no longer have access to the GCP instances, but if I do I will test your suggestion